Is there any Biblical prophecy about increased deaths as the end draws near?
This year there have been quite a significant number of deaths from murders, accidents and diseases like its never been witnessed before in my country. Every week I read on the newspaper that a couple fought and someone was killed or a celebrity died. I think this could be a birth pang described by Jesus in the gospel. Is there any Biblical basis that suggests murderous feelings will increase as the end draws near?

It is much easier to propagate and receive news from near and far than ever before making it difficult to know whether more evil is occurring or if it is just better reported.  We do know, however, that the love of many will grow cold:

And then shall many be offended, and shall betray one another, and shall hate one another. And many false prophets shall rise, and shall deceive many. And because iniquity shall abound, the love of many shall wax cold. - Matthew 24:10-12

And there will be a general worsening of the human disposition amongst those who are devoid of Christ:

This know also, that in the last days perilous times shall come. For men shall be lovers of their own selves, covetous, boasters, proud, blasphemers, disobedient to parents, unthankful, unholy, Without natural affection, trucebreakers, false accusers, incontinent, fierce, despisers of those that are good, Traitors, heady, highminded, lovers of pleasures more than lovers of God; - 2 Timothy 3:1-4

And many of those will appear, and parade as, and perhaps even believe that they belong to Christ:

Having a form of godliness, but denying the power thereof: from such turn away. For of this sort are they which creep into houses, and lead captive silly women laden with sins, led away with divers lusts, Ever learning, and never able to come to the knowledge of the truth. Now as Jannes and Jambres withstood Moses, so do these also resist the truth: men of corrupt minds, reprobate concerning the faith.- 2 Timothy 3:5-8

There is, perhaps, a growing evil in this world that is even blacker than mere murder.  There are false prophets propagating false doctrine from within the Bible and from without.  They appear, much like their spiritual father, as angels of light and lead many astray from the simplicity that is in Christ:

Beware lest any man spoil you through philosophy and vain deceit, after the tradition of men, after the rudiments of the world, and not after Christ. For in him dwelleth all the fulness of the Godhead bodily. - Colossians 2:8-9

And so they are here:  Going beyond what Scripture states by application of philosophy, vainly desiring followers and ear tickling 'yes men'; erecting religious superstructures with the wood, hay, and stubble of human tradition; applying to God's self-revealed glory those things which are of the creation and making God out to be in man's image.
These are deniers; by necessity acting godly while denying the power of godliness, which they cannot access because they deny the Father and the Son.  Minions of the evil one, snatching away the good seed from every inch of hardened heart.
Do not fear what men can do to the body but fear the wrath of the Lamb:

And fear not them which kill the body, but are not able to kill the soul: but rather fear him which is able to destroy both soul and body in hell. - Matthew 10:28

And abhor and avoid as the plague everyone with a new doctrine, a new prophesy, a secret teaching, an updated theology:  There are none from God.

For ever, O LORD, thy word is settled in heaven. - Psalm 119:89


Wow, very true Mike Borden. That was comprehensive, indeed the love of many has grown cold

There are a couple prophecies about the second coming that are related to turmoil that come to mind, though I don't know if these indicate/suggest increase murderous feelings.

Daniel 12:1

1 And at that time shall Michael stand up, the great prince which standeth for the children of thy people: and there shall be a time of trouble, such as never was since there was a nation even to that same time: and at that time thy people shall be delivered, every one that shall be found written in the book.


Matt 24:6-7

6 And ye shall hear of wars and rumours of wars: see that ye be not troubled: for all these things must come to pass, but the end is not yet.
7 For nation shall rise against nation, and kingdom against kingdom: and there shall be famines, and pestilences, and earthquakes, in divers places.



emphasis mine

The Trouble prophesied could also include the murders am witnessing, am really alarmed because maybe there is a disaster at the horizon and God is saving these people from that disaster by calling them before the disaster happens
